# Google Map JSON for low bandwidth networks

Tags: json, google-maps, navigation, google-maps-android-api-2, map-directions

How to change google map JSON so that redundant stuff is not downloaded and speed up an app on low bandwidth networks. For example app doesn't support navigation hence steps are not required in JSON which is also downloaded and makes app slow on low bandwidth networks.

For Example:-

Google Map JSON between source and destination:-

```
{
 "geocoded_waypoints" : [
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "ChIJbZ--gzESrjsRsmxa_tmvhlI",
     "types" : [ "route" ]
  },
  {
     "geocoder_status" : "OK",
     "place_id" : "Elk4NjksIDEydGggTWFpbiBSb2FkLCBLb3JhbWFuZ2FsYSAzIEJsb2NrLCBLb3JhbWFuZ2FsYSwgQmVuZ2FsdXJ1LCBLYXJuYXRha2EgNTYwMDM0LCBJbmRpYQ",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
],
"routes" : [
  {
     "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 12.959155,
           "lng" : 77.7091214
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 12.9206335,
           "lng" : 77.6264824
        }
     },
     "copyrights" : "Map data ©2015 Google",
     "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "12.5 km",
              "value" : 12510
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "29 mins",
              "value" : 1750
           },
           "end_address" : "869, 12th Main Road, Koramangala 3 Block, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560034, India",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 12.9280212,
              "lng" : 77.6267905
           },
           "start_address" : "PFS Driveway, Lakshminarayana Pura, AECS Layout, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India",
           "start_location" : {
              "lat" : 12.959155,
              "lng" : 77.70615509999999
           },
           "steps" : [
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.3 km",
                    "value" : 283
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 68
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9569421,
                    "lng" : 77.70609429999999
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esouth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003ePFS Driveway\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eRestricted usage road\u003c/div\u003e",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "wabnAo~gyMzK_AH?D@DD@F?F@N?D@J@D?F@D"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.959155,
                    "lng" : 77.70615509999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "26 m",
                    "value" : 26
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 6
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9567068,
                    "lng" : 77.70613229999999
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e to stay on \u003cb\u003ePFS Driveway\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eRestricted usage road\u003c/div\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "{sanAa~gyMl@G"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9569421,
                    "lng" : 77.70609429999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.1 km",
                    "value" : 138
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 59
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9568247,
                    "lng" : 77.70486409999999
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eMarathalli Bridge Service Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "mranAi~gyMC^Q|E"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9567068,
                    "lng" : 77.70613229999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "36 m",
                    "value" : 36
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 8
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9565042,
                    "lng" : 77.70486959999999
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eMunnekollal Main Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "csanAkvgyM~@A"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9568247,
                    "lng" : 77.70486409999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.5 km",
                    "value" : 482
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 83
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9563276,
                    "lng" : 77.7091214
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eMarathalli Bridge Service Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "cqanAmvgyMPkGFuCV_GHeB?K@CDWD]g@C"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9565042,
                    "lng" : 77.70486959999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.8 km",
                    "value" : 838
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "2 mins",
                    "value" : 142
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.956896,
                    "lng" : 77.70141439999999
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eMarathalli Bridge/Old Airport Rd/Varthur Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinue to follow Old Airport Rd/Varthur Rd\u003c/div\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "apanA_qhyMs@nVE|A?@AB?@ErBInAG~BMlCA^ARC^CR?B?@?r@AXA`@"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9563276,
                    "lng" : 77.7091214
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.4 km",
                    "value" : 411
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 62
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9533531,
                    "lng" : 77.7003715
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eNH7\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "ssanAy`gyMRJHDFDvBb@xBf@ZHpK`B"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.956896,
                    "lng" : 77.70141439999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "31 m",
                    "value" : 31
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 23
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9531397,
                    "lng" : 77.7001892
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eNH7\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "m}`nAizfyMHF^Z"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9533531,
                    "lng" : 77.7003715
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "3.8 km",
                    "value" : 3796
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "6 mins",
                    "value" : 373
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9274228,
                    "lng" : 77.6798031
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eNH7\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by VIMS Super Specialty Hospital (on the left in 550&nbsp;m)\u003c/div\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-slight-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "c|`nAeyfyM`Ft@lBRzFl@|Fj@x@JzATn@J`AR~A`@fB`@dB`@j@Ph@PhKdCr@R^HVJZJ`@Nb@RdAh@bAf@x@`@r@X\\N`@PtAp@pBdA~@f@`Ah@lAx@`Av@n@n@xB|BfBpBb@f@fBtBtDdE`AdAbCpC`CjCtC`DpIlJxF|G^h@PTNXXf@\\r@Th@p@dBl@~AjA~CxA~Dx@zBVp@p@hBr@hBJR"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9531397,
                    "lng" : 77.7001892
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "3.0 km",
                    "value" : 3010
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "5 mins",
                    "value" : 270
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9237183,
                    "lng" : 77.6540827
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e to stay on \u003cb\u003eNH7\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "keep-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "k{{mAwybyMRf@rBxFbD|I^~@\\~@~C`I^jAX|@Vv@zAnEfBlF|@~BvAbEtBfFZ|@hFbNT~@@J?J@J@J?L?JAL?LAJAJCLALEREXe@hC_AnEMr@Kn@a@xC]bCa@zBk@lCaA|D_AfD_AvDc@fBYrAMx@OlAe@vD"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9274228,
                    "lng" : 77.6798031
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.4 km",
                    "value" : 438
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 66
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.924442,
                    "lng" : 77.6501267
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at \u003cb\u003eAgra Exit\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eSarjapur Main Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "gd{mA_y}xMQb@Mv@QtAu@rGYjCCXCXA\\AXAP?P?r@"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9237183,
                    "lng" : 77.6540827
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "1.8 km",
                    "value" : 1816
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "5 mins",
                    "value" : 304
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9248137,
                    "lng" : 77.63406830000001
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eSarjapur Main Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Karthikshekar Hospital (on the left in 1.3&nbsp;km)\u003c/div\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "wh{mAi`}xMEDCDEFCFA@I`@I\\?@AV?R@|@?JD~@Dx@Bl@DtB@TDx@Dd@?NDz@?P@L?V?l@?nC@^@\\@P@H@DFTx@jD\\jBf@jC`@fCVjADVDP@H?H?JAH?FADADADCFCHmArEEL_BpFCHA@ADGJIRKPW`@[f@S^Wl@KXEJCJA@AHCFCHAHERCNANAPAD?F?F@PBVNtAPxB`@lELbA"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.924442,
                    "lng" : 77.6501267
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "77 m",
                    "value" : 77
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 44
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9250061,
                    "lng" : 77.6335821
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003e80 Feet Main Rd/Mahatyagi Laksmidevi Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "ak{mA}{yxMFfA@PSB]B"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9248137,
                    "lng" : 77.63406830000001
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.6 km",
                    "value" : 579
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "2 mins",
                    "value" : 101
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9245984,
                    "lng" : 77.62833669999999
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003e1st Cross Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by Sandeepani (on the right)\u003c/div\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "il{mA{xyxMDb@VdCL~APzBz@hILzBCh@Gl@i@rB"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9250061,
                    "lng" : 77.6335821
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.2 km",
                    "value" : 174
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 37
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9261219,
                    "lng" : 77.628711
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003e8th Main Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "wi{mAcxxxM_Dk@uBYYC"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9245984,
                    "lng" : 77.62833669999999
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.3 km",
                    "value" : 264
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 58
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9270734,
                    "lng" : 77.6264824
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003e3rd Cross Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "gs{mAmzxxMe@zAe@xA}@lCs@xB"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9261219,
                    "lng" : 77.628711
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              },
              {
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "0.1 km",
                    "value" : 111
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "1 min",
                    "value" : 46
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9280212,
                    "lng" : 77.6267905
                 },
                 "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003e12th Main Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003ePass by the park (on the right)\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDestination will be on the right\u003c/div\u003e",
                 "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                 "polyline" : {
                    "points" : "ey{mAolxxM}D}@"
                 },
                 "start_location" : {
                    "lat" : 12.9270734,
                    "lng" : 77.6264824
                 },
                 "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
              }
           ],
           "via_waypoint" : []
        }
     ],
     "overview_polyline" : {
        "points" : "wabnAo~gyMdL_AJFBd@BX@Dl@GU|F~@APkG^uKHqBF[D]g@Cy@lYAFErBInAUlGKfBArAA`@RJPJpFjAlLjBh@b@`Ft@lBRxNxAtC`@pB^fEbApCr@rLvCfCt@dAb@hCpAlD|AfEvB`CpAlAx@`Av@hDlDhLtM|MdOpIlJxF|Gp@~@h@`Ar@|AdGdPvD`K^z@vGvQ|@~B~C`I^jAp@tBbE|LtCbIpCdHhFbNT~@@VBp@Er@QhAeBxIYbB_A|Ga@zBk@lCaA|D_AfDcB~Gg@lCu@dGQb@Mv@gAhJ]dDEv@CpBSZUbA?tBJxBHbDLdCFrB?|DB|@BZHZvAvGhArGd@~BAf@IXwD|MO\\iAnBk@lAQd@K^Ov@En@Dp@pA`NHxAq@F|@dKz@hILzBKvAi@rB_Dk@oC]}D|L}D}@"
     },
     "summary" : "NH7",
     "warnings" : [],
     "waypoint_order" : []
  }
],
 "status" : "OK"
}
```

Required JSON for some application:-

```
    {
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJbZ--gzESrjsRsmxa_tmvhlI",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "Elk4NjksIDEydGggTWFpbiBSb2FkLCBLb3JhbWFuZ2FsYSAzIEJsb2NrLCBLb3JhbWFuZ2FsYSwgQmVuZ2FsdXJ1LCBLYXJuYXRha2EgNTYwMDM0LCBJbmRpYQ",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 12.959155,
               "lng" : 77.7091214
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 12.9206335,
               "lng" : 77.6264824
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2015 Google",
"legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "12.5 km",
                  "value" : 12510
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "29 mins",
                  "value" : 1750
               },
               "end_address" : "869, 12th Main Road, Koramangala 3 Block, Koramangala, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560034, India",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 12.9280212,
                  "lng" : 77.6267905
               },
               "start_address" : "PFS Driveway, Lakshminarayana Pura, AECS Layout, Marathahalli, Bengaluru, Karnataka 560037, India",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 12.959155,
                  "lng" : 77.70615509999999
               },
}
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "wabnAo~gyMdL_AJFBd@BX@Dl@GU|F~@APkG^uKHqBF[D]g@Cy@lYAFErBInAUlGKfBArAA`@RJPJpFjAlLjBh@b@`Ft@lBRxNxAtC`@pB^fEbApCr@rLvCfCt@dAb@hCpAlD|AfEvB`CpAlAx@`Av@hDlDhLtM|MdOpIlJxF|Gp@~@h@`Ar@|AdGdPvD`K^z@vGvQ|@~B~C`I^jAp@tBbE|LtCbIpCdHhFbNT~@@VBp@Er@QhAeBxIYbB_A|Ga@zBk@lCaA|D_AfDcB~Gg@lCu@dGQb@Mv@gAhJ]dDEv@CpBSZUbA?tBJxBHbDLdCFrB?|DB|@BZHZvAvGhArGd@~BAf@IXwD|MO\\iAnBk@lAQd@K^Ov@En@Dp@pA`NHxAq@F|@dKz@hILzBKvAi@rB_Dk@oC]}D|L}D}@"
         },
         "summary" : "NH7",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which API you are using and how your request look like

Comment: @Verma using Google Map API v2 and please refer my edit for request format etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Omitting parts of the JSON response is not a functionality in the APIs.

If you wish to request this, please do so in the issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Directions%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request

However, I wouldn't expect this to be ever part of the API. For one thing, it sounds like it'd be of limited use, and it can be implemented in your own server: proxy requests to the API, then trim responses.

Perhaps you could also use SPDY:
https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/